# Onfocus input mudar type e atribuir um value ao mesmo tempo

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, tenho o seguinte código.

O que eu tenho hoje é que ao clicar no `input` ele muda o `input` para date, porém gostaria que ao clicar ele continue mudando e atribua uma data, já tentei por o `onfocus="(this.value='2018-06-21')"` junto ao outro `onfocus` que já tenho mas sem sucesso.

```html
<input type="text" name="dtfinal" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onfocusout="(this.type='text')" placeholder="Data Final">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta separar com vírgula.

```html
<input type="text" name="dtfinal" onfocus="(this.value = '2018-06-21', this.type='date')" onfocusout="(this.type='text')" placeholder="Data Final">
```